# React Native Add Back Button Functionality to Bottom Tab

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am attempting to create a mobile application that has a back button on the bottom navigation bar. I will have three options on the tab bar: Back, Home and Settings. Home has 6 buttons that lead to different screens. When I navigate through these screens, I want the Back button to work as the default header back button does.

As I am using multiple screens, the back button has no stack history so navigation.goBack() does not work. When I check navigation.canGoBack() it returns true bit navigation.state is undefined. I think it is because the bottom tab is the parent and cannot see the navigation stack of the children but I cannot find a workaround for this.

I have tried nesting the BottomTabNavigator within a StackNavigator and vice versa but can't get it working. I have found no solutions online even though I have looked. I have considered creating a new bottom tab for each screen so that the back button would not be a parent and be in the correct stack but I'm not sure that would work and it is not very efficient coding.

I can post my code but it is not very helpful since I have been trying many different things.

[Homepage:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fik8T.png) 
The picture shows my homepage with the bottom navigation bar. I want to be able to navigate to Medication, then navigate to other screens within medication (like the one here: [Medication1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U22Q8.png)), and be able to use the back button on the bottom left as the default back button in the header does.

I used this code snippet on the reactnavigation docs but it does not work for navigate.goBack():

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Chat"
  component={Chat}
  listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
    tabPress: (e) => {
      // Prevent default action
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do something with the `navigation` object
      navigation.navigate('AnotherPlace');
    },
  })}
/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You can try to make a custom bottom tab bar and try the built-in API for going back

Comment: @EmadBaqeri could you expand on this please? I have tried to use what I can find in the documentation but am still struggling.

Comment: Hey friend, as it is not any good to have a back button at the bottom tab bar, you should not see anything on the web for that. But for more elaboration I'm suggesting you make a custom bottom tab bar for your application, you can find some sample codes and tutorials for a custom bottom tab for react-native, and then you can any functionality you want to your buttom tab

Comment: @EmadBaqeri I will look into that now, I think creating a custom bottom tab will still have the same issue with being a parent component so would not have the current screen navigation stack. To avoid this, I could place a custom bottom tab on every screen but I am trying to not do that unless I have to

Comment: No you shouldn’t add the custom bottom tab for each screen, there is an API that will let you know about the screen that you are in, useNavigation()